# How to create additional Oracle 11g database on Linux?

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration, oracle-xe

I have already created a database XE on my linux desktop.Please find the below information about the database.

`ORACLE_SID=XE
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe`

I have to create another database,eg: database name is DB1. 
My question is how canI set ORACLE_HOME for DB1 and other parameters in pfile ?

Also how can I avoid the error `ORA-45301: XE Edition single instance violation error`?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Express Edition is a free (as in "free beer") version of the Oracle database. As such it comes with various limitations compared to the paid for versions. These are covered [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#XEINL116).

> "I have to create another database"

You cannot do this with XE. From [the Installation guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#XEINL117):

> "Only one installation of Oracle Database XE can be performed on a
>   single computer..... In addition, users can run only one instance of
>   the Oracle Database XE database on each individual computer. "

This is why you get the `ORA-45301` error. If you need a second XE database you need a second computer. Or upgrade to Standard Edition.

Comment: let me know how to upgrade to Standard Edition ?

Comment: Well first you need to buy a license

Comment: i want to install 11g database on linux. let me know how to install the Oracle 11gR2 on linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: Tim Hall is the man for you. [Check it out](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/articles-11g#db11g_release_2_installations)